# contrasting impression

Tags: adjectives

Hello fellow stackexchangers!
My student submitted a movie review where she wrote the film had made a 'contrast impression' on her. I corrected it to 'contrasting', but now I'm wondering: can one even say that? In my native tongue, we say something like 'twofold' or 'double', but 'twofold impression' is impossible, right?
P.S. - I did not bother with context as I thought it would be pretty obvious what she meant: she goes on to write "On the one hand, I am fascinated by the themes..." bla bla, "On the other, the way they were presented made me just want to say WHAAAT?" - so basically yes, it's the way Barmar here understood it: I liked this but hated this.

Comment: "Contrasting impression" is grammatical and meaningful in certain contexts.  But what did the student mean to say?  A contrasting impression would be an impression that contrasts with something else.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What was her complete sentence and what did she say before and after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is *contradictory*. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/contradictory) has the following relevant definition:

> 1.1 Containing elements which are inconsistent.
>   *‘politically he exhibited contradictory behaviour’*

So your friend could say:

> I had contradictory impressions of the movie. I liked the actors, but hated the plotline.

Comment: Thank you, I looked it up in other contexts, and I think that's it. Thanks.